# Cleaning umbraco history in MySQL

Tags: mysql, umbraco

After updating umbraco from version 7.1 to 7.2 I've started to have issues fetching data.
I've noticed I cannot get InternalIndexer Examine index to finish rebuilding which I thought would fix my problem.
I read that having a big database could cause this issue so I'm trying to clean my database of historic data.
I found a script that does this but it's written for SQL Server and I'm having issues converting this to MySQL.

Can anyone help me convert this script or maybe have a different one I can use?
The SQL Server script is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeleteHistory]

AS

BEGIN

Select VersionID into #tmp FROM cmsDocument

WHERE versionID NOT IN  (SELECT D.versionId FROM cmsDocument D 

WHERE D.versionId IN (SELECT versionId FROM (SELECT CV.versionId, published, newest, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY CV.versionDate DESC) RowNum
FROM cmsContentVersion CV JOIN cmsDocument DD ON CV.versionId = DD.versionId
WHERE DD.nodeId = D.nodeId) AS tmp
WHERE tmp.RowNum <= 3 OR tmp.published = 1 OR tmp.newest = 1)  )

DELETE FROM cmsPreviewXml WHERE VersionId IN (select #tmp.VersionId from #tmp)

DELETE FROM cmsContentVersion WHERE VersionId IN (select #tmp.VersionId from #tmp)

DELETE FROM cmsPropertyData WHERE VersionId IN (select #tmp.VersionId from #tmp)

DELETE FROM cmsDocument WHERE VersionId IN (select #tmp.VersionId from #tmp)

END
```

And what I have so far is:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp

Select      VersionID FROM      cmsDocument  WHERE versionID NOT IN (   SELECT          D.versionId, D.NodeId   FROM        cmsDocument D   WHERE       D.versionId IN (            SELECT 
                versionId           FROM (
                SELECT 
                    CV.versionId, published, newest, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS RowNum  
                FROM 
                    cmsContentVersion CV
                        JOIN cmsDocument DD ON CV.versionId = DD.versionId
                    , (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
                WHERE 
                    DD.nodeId = D.NodeId
                ORDER BY
                    CV.versionDate DESC
                ) AS tmp                WHERE
                tmp.RowNum <= 3 OR tmp.published = 1 OR tmp.newest = 1
        ) )

DELETE FROM cmsPreviewXml WHERE VersionId IN (select VersionId from tmp)

DELETE FROM cmsContentVersion WHERE VersionId IN (select VersionId from tmp)

DELETE FROM cmsPropertyData WHERE VersionId IN (select VersionId from tmp)

DELETE FROM cmsDocument WHERE VersionId IN (select VersionId from tmp)

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE tmp
```

Hope you guys can help me.

Thanks

Comment: Have you triend deleting the client dependency data and the internal index data in ~/App_Data/TEMP/ExamineIndexes/Internal/Index/. 

After deleting and before you open you're site restart the AppPool.

Finally login into Umbraco and republish the whole site and that should force the index to rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same matter, I solved it like this:

```
SET GLOBAL connect_timeout=28800;
SET GLOBAL wait_timeout=28800;
SET GLOBAL interactive_timeout=28800;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp (
    Select versionId from (
        Select * From (
            SELECT CV.versionID , @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS RowNum
            FROM cmsContentVersion CV
            JOIN cmsDocument DD ON CV.versionId = DD.versionId, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
            WHERE (Newest=0 and published=0) 
            ORDER BY DD.nodeId, CV.VersionDate DESC
            ) Old
        Where RowNum > 3
    ) Old2
);
SELECT Count(*) from tmp;
DELETE FROM cmsPreviewXml WHERE VersionId IN (select VersionId from tmp);
DELETE FROM cmsContentVersion WHERE VersionId IN (select VersionId from tmp);
DELETE FROM cmsPropertyData WHERE cmsPropertyData.VersionId IN (select VersionId from tmp);
DELETE FROM cmsDocument WHERE VersionId IN (select VersionId from tmp);
DELETE FROM umbracolog WHERE LOGHEADER='Error'
```

Ciao,
   Michele